# Can 'extra_vars' receive multiple files?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

According the Ansible documentation [defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime), it says I can load variables from a file.

```
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars  "@some_file"
```

However, in my case I have **two files** containing extra variables for my playbook invocation.

Concatenating them together is not an option because one is a secret file created and keyed using Vault. The other file is generated from an upstream process.

I have tried:

```
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars  "@some_file @some_other_file"
```

... but it didn't work. Upon invocation I get

> ERROR: file could not read: some_file @some_other_file

so my guess is it takes everything after the first @ symbols as the path of the file.

My questions is, can extra-vars accept multiple files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out I can use:

```
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars=@some_file --extra-vars=@some_other_file
```

This does work for me. Please let me know if there is a better answer. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting this for now as there are no new responses for a week.