# Ansible: What is the variable order/precedence in case of multiple 'extra_vars' files?

Tags: ansible

In this older question about "[Can `extra_vars` receive multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800060/)", the original poster answered the question, saying that multiple vars files could be accomplished by just using multiple `--extra-vars` parameters.

The followup question that I have is that, in such a case, where the `ansible-playbook` command line has two `--extra-vars` parameters, each pointing to a different file, what is the order or precedence of those files?

Also, what happens if both files have the same var name (e.g., `my_host`) in them?

For example, say I have 2 files, `extraVars1.yml` and `extraVars2.yml` and in the `ansible-playbook` command line I have:

```
ansible-playbook... --extra-vars "@extraVars1.yml" --extra-vars "@extraVars2.yml"
```

and the `extraVars1.yml` file has:

```
my_host: 1.2.3.4
```

and the `extraVars2.yml` file has:

```
my_host: 5.6.7.8
```

What will the value of the `my_host` var be when the playbook is run?

Thanks!
Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the Ansible documentation about **Using Variables** and [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

> `extra vars` (for example, `-e "user=my_user"`) (always win precedence)
>
> In general, Ansible gives precedence to variables that were defined more recently ...

This means the last defined wins.

Lets have a short test here with a `vars.yml` playbook.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    my_host: 9.0.0.0

  tasks:

  - name: Show value
    debug:
      msg: "{{ my_host }}"
```

The execution of `ansible-playbook vars.yml` will result into an output of

```
TASK [Show value] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 9.0.0.0
```

The execution of `ansible-playbook -e "@extraVars1.yml" vars.yml` will result into an output of

```
TASK [Show value] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 1.2.3.4
```

The execution of `ansible-playbook -e "@extraVars1.yml" -e "@extraVars2.yml" vars.yml` will result into an output of

```
TASK [Show value] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 5.6.7.8
```

The execution of `ansible-playbook -e "@extraVars2.yml" -e "@extraVars1.yml" vars.yml` will result into an output of

```
TASK [Show value] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!